# Keep getting a an error.. dont know how to finish this

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class homework {

    public static  void main(String[] args) {
        double Xp;
        double Yp;
        double Xq;
        double Yq;

        Scanner Point1= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the First value for Xp: ");
        Xp = Point1.nextDouble();
        Scanner Point2= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Eneter the First valuse for Yp: ");
        Yp = Point2.nextDouble();
        Scanner Point3= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the First valuse for Xq: ");
        Xq = Point3.nextDouble();
        Scanner Point4= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the First valuse for Yq: ");
        Yq = Point4.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Point P's Coordinates are: " + "( " + Xp + "," + Yp   + ")" );
        System.out.println("Point Q's Coordinates are: " + "( " + Xq + "," + Yq   + ")" );


        if ( Xp >= 1 &&  Yp >= 0) 
        {
         System.out.println("The point P is in Quadrant 1 ");
        }
       else if ( Xp <= 0 && Yp>=0 )
       {
        System.out.println("The point P is in Quadrant 2" );
       }
       else if ( Xp<=0 && Yp<0)
       {
        System.out.println("The point P is in Quadrant 3" );    
       }
       else if (Xp>= 0 && Yp<0)
       {
        System.out.println("The point P is in Quadrant 4" );    
       }  
       if ( Xq >= 1 &&  Yq >= 0) 
       {
         System.out.println("The point Q is in Quadrant 1 ");
       }
      else if ( Xq <= 0 && Yq>=0 )
      {
        System.out.println("The point Q is in Quadrant 2" );
      }
      else if ( Xq<=0 && Yq<0)
      {
        System.out.println("The point Q is in Quadrant 3" );    
      }
      else if (Xq>= 0 && Yq<0)
      {
        System.out.println("The point Q is in Quadrant 4" );
        }      
    double ED=Math.sqrt((Xq-Xp)*(Xq-Xp) + (Yq-Yp)*(Yq-Yp));
    System.out.println("The Euclidean distance from p to q is :"+ ED);

    double slope= (Yp-Yq)/(Xp-Xq);
    if (Xp-Xq!=0)
    {
    double slope;
    System.out.println("The Slope of the Line is: "+ slope);
    }
    else if  (Xp-Xq==0){
    System.out.println("Slope Is Undefined");
    System.exit(1);
}} }
```

The error is that I duplicated variable  `slope` and i can't figure out how to make it work without getting an error.

What my assigment is asking for:

> (Create another method that returns the slope of the line pq formed by
>   connecting p and q. The slope is expressed as m = (yp − yq)/(xp − xq),
>   but it must be robust to errors caused by certain inputs.If the slope
>   is undefined, do not perform the calculation due to a divide-by zero
>   error. Instead, print the error message “Slope is undefined.” inside
>   the method and call System.exit(1) to end your program)

Comment: So you say you get an error but don't post the error? I LIKE IT!  *HINT: Post the error log please and thank you*

Comment: obviously the error is that there is no error.

Comment: or the error is of the 'guess, check, refine' variety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only "error" I currently see is that you have a duplicate of your variable "slope".
Another thing to mention: Don't use multiple Scanner. You can just use one and do the inputs you want. And close the Scanner after your inputs are done.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
    double slope;
```

from

```
    double slope= (Yp-Yq)/(Xp-Xq);
    if (Xp-Xq!=0){
        double slope;        // just remove this.
        System.out.println("The Slope of the Line is: "+ slope);

    }else if  (Xp-Xq==0){
        System.out.println("Slope Is Undefined");
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

**Further** 
You can create a class and several methods to do all these operations and use the main method to get the  user inputs through Scanner and invoke functions through an object of that class. This will make your code cleaner.

For an example, create a class called Geomat

```
    class Geomat{ 
        public void getQuadrant(){
             // do your logic here
        }

        public void getSlope(){
             // do your logic here
        }

    }
```

then in main method after getting inputs from the Scanner use

```
    Geomat g = new Geomat();
    g.getQuadrant();
    g.getSlope();
```